# Visual Studio Publishing throws System.AggregateException without details at main development-System

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, publish

[Visual Studio Error at Publishing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p45S9.png)

Hello,
this is my first Question on this board, but i got plenty of good answers from here recently so i hope somebody could help with this specific problem:

I want to realize .net core Applications running on a Raspberry pi 4 and everything works pretty fine except that my Visual Studio throws a strange Error everytime i try to Publish the dotnetcoreapp3.1 as Self-contained linux-arm.

The Error says further there would be more information in the output log-file, but i checked it and it just said the same undetermined Error:

```
22.04.2020 22:44:33
```

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details. <---

System.Exception: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details.

===================

I tried to publish the project at another device with Visual Studio and it worked fine, after that i deinstalled visual studio and reinstalled it, after this not working i tried to repair with still no effect.

I hope somebody has an Idea how i can fix this ^^

Sincerely yours

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by deleting an old unavailable nuget-path